# Weight Painting Issue only shows up on render

Tags: rendering, weight-painting

I've got the model set up with weight painting and it looks perfectly fine in Blender. When I render an image I can see it tearing through though. What causes the difference during the render and how can I prevent it? See the right leg in the below image. (I have noticed this on another model as well.)

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? You can remove the unnecessary elements if you want